# How can I autolock / awaken an iPad if the home button is disabled or covered?

Tags: ios, ipad, kiosk

I am building an iPad Kiosk App and my customer wants the iPad to be "locked into" the app to keep users focused :) I have found two solutions to this. One is a lovely kiosk case which covers the home button, the other is setting SBStoreDemoAppLock as outlined in http://rick-hawkins.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/turning-ipad-into-kiosk-device.html
But the customer is also worried about screen burnout (and burn in) and wants to be sure the iPad goes to sleep, or at the very least to a screen saver, when inactive. If I have disabled the home button though, I cannot let the iPad go to sleep because it cannot be woken again. Ideally touching the screen would awake the iPad and go straight back into the app.
Is there a solution that doesn't involve me creating a fake sleep feature or screen saver as part of my app?

Comment: Is the lock button disabled/covered as well?

Comment: Yes, it is. These nifty enclosures cover everything but the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not worry about "burn-in", these aren't CRTs from the 1980s.  Also, it has been announced that this type of feature will be available in iOS 6.0, so you may want to wait a few months and use 6.0.

Comment: I'm not so worried but my customers are .... but thanks for the heads up about ios6. [ios6 Guided Access](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/06/26/ios-6-guided-access/) looks great.